# A question about the name of a property of positive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are positive integers such that every **prime** number which divides $n$ also divides $m$ (e.g. $n=25$ and $m=10$). How do you call such numbers? having the same "prime base" ? 
Thanks!

Comment: m= 10 and n= 25 are NOT an example of "every prime number that divides m also divides n".  The prime number "2" divides 10 but does not divide 25.

Comment: I thinks it was ok...any way, thanks for the comment @user247327.

Comment: does every prime number that divides m also have to divide n? If not then m is just a multiple of n.

Comment: no, i mean that $m$ satysfies the following condition :  $p\mid n\to p\mid m$

Comment: It seems cand has the right terminology

Comment: It's equivalent to: $n$ divides some power of $m$, or $\,{\rm rad}(n)\mid m,\,$ or $\,{\rm rad}(n)\mid  {\rm rad}(m)$ where $\,{\rm rad}(n)\,$ denotes the [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) of $\,n = $ product of its distinct prime factors. Computing the radical is important in (algebraic) number theory, but there is [no known fast algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/171571/242)

Comment: Your question is equivalent to "What do you call $m$ when $rad(n)\mid m$?" I think you just say $m\equiv 0 \mod{rad(n)}$. As I typed this, I see Bill Dubuque says about the same.