# Self-contained formal polynomial reference

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials

In the [forward](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-0-387-27475-1%2F1.pdf) to the [third edition](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-0-387-22025-3) of his *Undergraduate Algebra*, Lang mentions:

> A new section in Chapter IV gives a complete account of the Mason-Stothers theorem about polynomials, with Noah Snyder's beautifully simple proof. It is worth emphasizing that the derivative for polynomials is a purely algebraic operation, for which limits are not required. A Springer pamphlet has been published to present a self-contained treatment of polynomials (from scratch) culminating with this topic.

What publication is he referring to?

Comment: That proof was already known long before Snyder's publication. It is obvious if one is familiar with Wronskian dependence measures, e.g. see my 1996 sci.math post excerpted in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52819/242).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the following article (at least, Serge Lang is talking about it):

Noah Snyder **An alternate proof of Mason’s theorem**, Elem. Math. 55 (2000), 93–94; Springer Verlag.

This gives a ‘proof from the Book’ for Mason’s ABC theorem.