# Davenport's theorem general case (Algebra by S Lang).

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This is in regards to question 13 from chapter 4 of Lang. I got the case when $f,g$ are coprime, and for the general case I got the point where if $A$ is the gcd of $f$ and $g$, and $f'$, $g'$ are such, that, $Af'=f$, and $Ag'=g$, deg $f' \leq $ 2deg $((f')^3-(g')^2) - 2 \implies $ deg $f$ + 3 deg $A \leq $ 2deg $( f^2f' - g^2) - 2$. But I cannot show that deg$(f^2f'-g^2) \leq$ deg$(f^3-g^2)+ 3$deg$A$. Is the way I'm going about it wrong, I cannot see how to apply the hint Lang gave either.

Edit for Clarification
The question being asked is to prove that deg$(f) \leq$ deg$(f^3 - g^2) - 2$, when $f,g$ are polynomials over an algebraically closed field. [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlWZV.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Davenport's theorem follows immediately from Mason's $abc$ theorem for polynomials - which has [a very short elementary proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52819/242).